# Java, Spring, прогресс бар, как обновлять?

Tags: java, spring, http, progress-bar

Хочу сделать прогресс бар, который будет давать представление о времени выполнения операции
Примерно такой https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/progress/#animated-stripes

Планирую, создать js Ajax запрос, который будет каждые 5-10 сек опрашивать метод, который будет выдавать информацию о проценте выполнения и обновлять данные на странице, после выполнения на 100% прекратить опрос.

Правильный ли у меня ход мыслей и является ли это хорошей практикой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Распространенный подход к этой задаче действительно состоит в том, чтобы первым запросом инициировать длительную асинхронную операцию, а последующими запросами с каким-то интервалом узнавать статус и опционально в итоге получить что-то (например построенный отчет).

Оформить это можно двумя способами, либо каким-то их сочетанием

### Способ 1. Рабоче-крестьянский.

Просто гоняем JSON, как мы все привыкли.

Клиент отправляет запрос на создание асинхронной задачи.

```
POST /report HTTP/1.1
```

Получает ответ, что сущность "задача" создана и можно отрисовывать прогрессбар.

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created

{ "id": "12345678", "status": "PENDING" }
```

После этого клиент дергает ресурс задачи по какому-то расписанию, пока не получит желаемый ответ:

```
GET /report/12345678 HTTP/1.1
```

Сервер будет отвечать что-то вроде:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{ "id": "12345678", "status": "PROCESSING", "progress": 10 }

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{ "id": "12345678", "status": "PROCESSING", "progress": 20 }

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{ "id": "12345678", "status": "FINISHED", "progress": 100, 
  "result": { ................. }}
```

### Способ 2. Изысканный

Для тех кто чтит HTTP спецификации и не любит мешать технические метаданные с бизнес-данными. Можно добавить, например, гарантированное время ожидания ответа клиентом на случай, если задача будет быстро обработана.

```
POST /report HTTP/1.1
Prefer: wait=20
```

Сервер либо отчитается о сразу выполненной задаче, указав в Location местонахождение результата, возможно даже сразу вернув его:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: /report/12345678

или

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 1024

<........... результат асинхронной операции  ............>
```

либо сообщит, что принял задачу в обработку, и укажет, где узнавать статус

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Location: /report/12345678/status
```

Клиент опять же будет с каким-то интервалом  проверять статус:

```
GET /report/12345678/status HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 102 Processing
Location: /report/12345678/status 
Progress: 1/4 "Проверка курсов валют" 

HTTP/1.1 102 Processing
Location: /report/12345678/status
Progress: 2/4 "Свожу балансы" 

HTTP/1.1 102 Processing
Location: /report/12345678/status
Progress: 3/4 "Почти готово"
```

Когда сервер закончит обработку, он опять-таки ответит локацией результата или сразу вернет его.

```
GET /report HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Progress: 4/4 "Готово"
Location: /report/12345678

или

HTTP/1.1 200 Created
Progress: 4/4 "Готово"
Location: /report/12345678
Content-Length: 1024

<........... результат асинхронной операции  ............>
```

---

Обращу внимание, что данные заголовки и коды ответов не стандартизированы хотя и предпринимаются попытки (см. ниже). Какие-то слишком строгие клиенты, реверс-прокси и веб-фреймворки в теории могут отказаться обрабатывать что-то из этого.

Ссылки для вдохновения:

- [Draft: Reporting Progress of Long-Running Operations in HTTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-wright-http-progress-02)
- [RFC7240: Prefer Header for HTTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7240)
- [RFC7231: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Semantics and Content](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231)